# how to dynamic select today date in cypress.command()?

Tags: date, command, cypress, cypress-custom-commands

I have a command where I can enter a specific date for start date, please see below a part of the command I am using.

[image: cy.commands]

and when I am calling it in the test I need to enter a dynamic date like **today <=(+30 days)**

```
cy.create123((new Date().getDate() - 1), '2023-08-07')
```

ofc it did not work, but I have no idea how can I do it. How I can setup to cy.command to get always today-1 as startDate!

My issue is to make the dynamic enter date to work on **Cypress.Commands()**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TLDR

Install [dayjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dayjs) and use

```js
const startDate = dayjs().add(-1, 'day').format('YYYY-MM-DD')

cy.create123(startDate, '2023-08-07')
```

---

The Custom Command and the `cy.request()` inside it are expecting the date as a ***string*** type.

Your calculated dynamic date `(new Date().getDate() - 1)` is giving you a ***number*** type.

But `.toISOString()` only works on ***Date*** types, not ***number*** types.

So after doing math on the Date(), you get a **number** which must be converted into a **Date** and then into a **string**.

```js
const today = new Date()
const yesterday = new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate() -1))
const startDate = yesterday.toISOString()
```

But even that's not the end of the problems, because the **timezone** might give you invalid dates.

I recommend using `dayjs` as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Instead of subtracting 1, I am decreasing the day with 24 hours.

```js
cy.create123(new Date(Date.now() - (3600 * 1000 * 24)).getUTCDate(), '2023-08-07')
```

Considering today is 29 Aug, this will give the output as 28.

[image: date]

To get the date in the format `yyyy-mm-dd` use:

```js
new Date(Date.now() - ( 3600 * 1000 * 24)).toISOString().slice(0, 10)
```

[image: date formatted]

Comment: the code `cy.create123((new Date().getDay() - 1), '2023-08-07')` is not working.
neither did `cy.create123(new Date(Date.now() - (3600 * 1000 * 24)).getUTCDate(), '2023-08-07')`

Comment: In which format do you want the date in your custom command ?

Comment: the date format is YYYY/MM/DD

Comment: `cy.create123((new Date().Date.now() - 1), '2023-08-07')` then it get the today day and not the today -1

Comment: please refer the updated answer.

Comment: The date format is already saved in another place and it will always be in the correct format. 
what I mean it did not work was, it do not get the correct day. the Today - 1 ..eg today is 29 - 1 so the date would be 28th august.

Comment: `new Date(Date.now() - ( 3600 * 1000 * 24)).toISOString().slice(0, 10)` and `cy.create123(new Date(Date.now() - (3600 * 1000 * 24)).getUTCDate(), '2023-08-07')` get the date 1970-01-01

Comment: Please check the code, it shouldn't give 1970-01-01. You can run the same code in the browser console. Attached a screenshot.

Comment: well, it does work on console, however it does not work the same way on cypress command. And my issue is to make it to work on cypress.commands()